# How can I redirect or capture session timeout event in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, web-applications, mojolicious, mojo

I'm writing a small application written with Mojolicious and I was wondering how I could go about alerting and/or redirect a user on session timeout?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the session cookie expires the browser will no longer send it with requests to the server. So when your server gets a request without a cookie to a restricted uri it needs to either redirect to the login screen, or tell the client app to do so.. which it should probably be doing already.